# Matrix over commutative ring with noncommutative diagonal perturbation

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I'm interested in the inverse and determinant properties of a relatively small matrix $A+D$, where $A\in M_n(R_c)$ for a commutative ring $R_c$ and $D\in M_n(R_n)$ is a diagonal matrix over a non-commutative ring $R_d$. Are there any special properties for such a matrix? E.g., Manin matrices are non-commutative, but many of the classical linear algebra results hold. This is not Manin, but has a nice structure compared to the general non-commutative setting.

Comment: Well, determinants aren't defined over general noncommutative rings. The best you can do are (Gelfand/Retakh/Wilson/etc. style) quasideterminants, which are in many ways closer to inverses than to determinants. So you're looking for a formula for the inverse. Have you looked at [formulas like Woodbury's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)? Some (all?) of them work over noncommutative rings. As it stands, your question is rather vague and broad...